# 2 * 2 * 2... j times without the ** operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponentiation

I am doing a challenge where I am supposed to calculate 2 * 2 * 2 ... j times, but without using the `**` operator.

I tried using square but when I thought about it, it couldn't be squaring.

```
N = int(input('Num: '))
x = 1
while True:
    if x * x > 0:
        break
    else:
        x += 1
print(x - 1 * x - 1)
```

The result should be 32 if I put in 5 but I actually get -1.

Comment: `x*x > 0` on the first iteration of the loop (`1*1 > 0`) so the loop immediately exits, when `x=1`... `1-1*1-1 == -1` hence it prints `-1`.

Comment: You should take the challenge more literally. Write a loop that runs `j` times and in each iteration multiplies `x` by 2.

Comment: `x - 1 * x - 1` will always be -1 as it is evaluated as if `(x - (1 * x)) - 1` which is always -1

Answer (score 4):

You can bit shift:

```
N = int(input('Num: '))
print(1 << N)
```

Or, just use the `pow` built-in, though it's basically the `**` operator:

```
N = int(input('Num: '))
print(pow(2, N))
```

If you wanted to use a loop:

```
N = int(input('Num: '))
result = 1
for _ in range(N):
    result *= 2
print(result)
```

Comment: you can also use a few standard modules to do - `functools.reduce(operator.mul, itertools.repeat(2, N))` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overcomplicating things:

```
j = int(input('Num: '))
x = 1
for _ in range(j):
   x *= 2
print(x)
```

or

```
j = int(input('Num: '))
x = 1
while j > 0:
    x *= 2
    j -= 1
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
math.pow(x, N)
```

That should do it!

Edit: math.pow will break for large values of N as described in the comments. Use the solution of Tomothy32 instead.

Comment: This will break for very large values.

Comment: And doesn't answer the question, which are about powers of `2`, and you don't need `math` - `pow` is a builtin.

Comment: Well it can do it for any value. Set x = 2 for this case.

Comment: @VictorSonck: It still won't work for large values; `math.pow` is `float`-oriented, and returns `float`, which means it will break for `N` of 1024 or larger (not to mention returning `float` for a logically `int` problem is a little odd even if it works).

Comment: `math.pow` is also slower than the `pow` built-in function, because it has to perform floating point operations.